# Why do we vote?

Tags: united-states, election, voting

There are increasingly amount of people saying voting does not matter (I could put a bunch of 1hr long youtube videos here). They argue the problem starts by having candidates that we don't really want to vote for.

So the election process is a process where there isn't really a choice, but a choice between several people of which none are suited to *rule* (in which ever kind of regime, as long as there are elections), in our opinion.

**Null Voting** is obviously an option on this scenario but does not solve the problem.

In a world were the vote is a [`False Dilemma`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma) as the one we currently live in, why does vote matter?
Is there a way to elect someone outside the options given (you may consider united-states as a concrete example)?

Comment: I think the premise of the question is (arguably) flawed in that there, of course, absolutely is a choice. The very definition of voting is choosing a particular choice on the ballot. The only answer that is really valid here is that apathetic people do not vote, others do.

Comment: By the way, there are far more than two candidates in the current US presidential election. Some states even allow write-in candidates.

Answer (score 0):

> why does vote matter?

I'm not sure this question is actually answerable. I think it's mostly opinion based. Here's mine:

If a voter is at the point where they feel their vote doesn't count, it's likely because they have been somewhat apathetic to the entire election process from the beginning.

To be fair, this isn't necessarily a bad thing. The fact that we have so much voter apathy in this country could indicate that things are running fairly smoothly as-is. At the end of the day, whether we have a democrat or a republican in the whitehouse, our nation seems to keep chugging along just fine.

However, for those that are extremely frustrated, they need to realize that these weren't two arbitrarily chosen individuals. These were individuals chosen by their respective parties...parties that consist of actual voters. Furthermore, to dwell upon the 'lack of choices for president' ignores the fact that their ballot has a whole lot more options than just president. And those other options are arguably much more important. Local politics is what ultimately influences national politics.

So, to answer this question:

> Is there a way to elect someone outside the options given

Yes...get involved early and locally to help influence the eventual options given.

Comment: -1: This post is a pure opinion. It must either contain an objective answer, backed with credible sources, or be removed altogether.

Comment: @bytebuster yep, hence me saying it's opinion and my comment on the question itself. :)

Comment: Absolutely. But what is the reason of giving a bad (subjective) answer to a bad question? :) I would totally understand if you were pursuing the *Reversal* badge, like someone did [here](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3481/have-any-transitional-fossils-missing-links-been-found)… (I'm just grumbling)